# Storing a command's output while also using exit status for an if statement

Tags: bash, optimization, sh

How can I optimize following Bash code?

```
if grep --quiet $pattern $fname; then
  echo "==> "$fname" <=="
  grep -n $pattern $fname
fi
```

Firstly it scans file for occurences of `$pattern`. If there were any results found, it prints file name and then all occurences.

You can see that it does same `grep` twice. If I could store results from first call and then reuse them, it would be perfect.

Comment: Consider running your code through http://shellcheck.net/, by the way -- it would find the quoting bugs I pointed out here. `echo "==> "$fname" <=="` is just particularly silly -- it comes *so close* to being right, but then goes out of its way to end the quotes before the `$fname` expansion! See item #14 in http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls

Comment: Thanks! I had a lot of those problems in rest of my script. I'm learning shell scripting from http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sh.html and it has soo many quirks.

Comment: There's a lot of good stuff on Bruce's page. That said, if you're looking for resources that cover shells above and beyond POSIX sh, I'd tend to suggest http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide (and the BashFAQ and other pages located on that same wiki); those resources are actively maintained by the folks in the freenode #bash channel, who (while sometimes prickly) tend to care deeply about accuracy and best practices.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An assignment won't change the value of `$?`, so you can add one without otherwise modifying your logic:

```
if content=$(grep -n "$pattern" "$fname"); then
  echo "==> $fname <=="
  printf '%s\n' "$content"
fi
```

Note, here, that all the variable expansions are inside double quotes. For some reason your original was explicitly performing them only unquoted -- this causes both string-splitting and glob expansion to take place; you almost certainly don't want either.

---

By the way -- there are things you could do that *would* make an assignment modify the exit status of a command run in the subshell generating its value! Using `declare`, `export`, `local`, or the like to perform an assignment will cause that command's own exit status to replace that of the subshell being assigned.

```
# here, the "local" will replace $? with 0
$ f() {
>   local foo=$(echo "bar"; exit 1)
>   echo "$?"
> }
$ f
0
```

...whereas...

```
# here, the "local" is separate, so the subshell's exit status survives
$ f() {
>   local foo
>   foo=$(echo "bar"; exit 1)
>   echo "$?"
> }
$ f
1
```